Find all unique quintuplets in an array that sum to a given target
Inspiration: Leetcode's [3Sum] link

Problem
Given an array nums of n (not necessarily distinct) integers, and given a target number target, return an array of all of the unique quintuplets [nums[a],nums[b],nums[c],nums[d],nums[e]] such that the following conditions are held:

0 <= a,b,c,d,e < n (or 1 <= a,b,c,d,e <= n if using 1-indexing)
All of a,b,c,d,e are distinct.
nums[a] + nums[b] + nums[c] + nums[d] + nums[e] = target

In the case of multiple arrays, we also add the requirements that at least two values in each of the arrays are distinct.



If all 3 conditions cannot be satisfied, you can return a junk value of your liking, or just an empty array [[]]. The testcases down below will use -1 as the specified junk value.
You may return the answer in any order. For example, given the array [-5,-2,-2,1,3,4,6] and target 0, you could return any permutation of [[-5,-2,-2,3,6]]. You do not need to return all possible permutations of one single array.

Testcases:
# Note: Thank you all for the additional test cases! However,
#       I will not be taking any more at this time just so the
#       question doesn't appear on the [Home] page for too long.

 Array: [-5,-2,-2,1,3,4,6]
Target: 0
Output: [[-5,-2,-2,3,6]]

 Array: [-5,-4,-2,0,1,2,6]
Target: 1
Output: [[-5,-2,0,2,6],[-4,-2,0,1,6]]

# Note that outputting `[[-4,-2,0,1,6],[-5,-2,0,2,6]]` is also valid,
# although returning just `[[-4,-2,0,1,6]]` or `[[-5,-2,0,2,6]]` is not.

 Array: [0,-1,2,3]
Target: 4
Output: -1

 Array: [0,1,-9,6,7]
Target: 6
Output: -1

 Array: [0,1,9,9,5]
Target: 45
Output: -1

 Array: [1,4,6,9,-4]
Target: 16
Output: [[1,4,6,9,-4]]

 Array: [1,0,9,6,5,0]
Target: 21
Output: [[1,0,9,6,5]]

 Array: [1,0,9,6,5,4,7]
Target: 21
Output: [[1,0,9,6,5],[1,0,9,4,7]]

 Array: [1,0,9,6,5,4,4,7]
Target: 21
Output: [[1,0,9,6,5],[1,0,9,4,7],[0,6,4,4,7],[1,5,4,4,7]]

# Above test case suggested by @Shaggy

 Array: [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4]
Target: 11
Output: [[1,2,2,3,3],[1,1,2,3,4]]

# Above test case suggested by @Arnauld

This is code-golf, so the shortest solution wins!

Suggested test case: [1,0,9,6,5,4,4,7], 21.

@Shaggy Added .

What's the source for this problem?

@xnor Sorry, should've added that. My inspiration for this was from Leetcode's "3Sum" problem.

shouldn't the last test case be [[1,0,9,6,5],[1,0,9,4,7],[0,6,4,4,7],[1,5,4,4,7]]? all of the current answers (and mine) return that.

@nyxbird My bad, I'll fix that

Suggested test case: [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4], 11

Could you please elaborate the first condition? I read it at as all elements in the quintuplet must be less than the length of nums . This is not right as your test case has a 9 and 6 in [1,0,9,6,5,0] which is greater than 5. Thank you

@IntroductionToProbability a,b,c,d,e are all list indices, not the actual values.

@Crsb0001 Forgive me but I am having a slow day. What is the implication of the first restriction?

Python 3, 95 bytes
f=lambda t,a,*p:[p][t*t:len(p)==5]or{i for v in[*a]for i in f(t-a.pop(0),[*a],*sorted([*p,v]))}

Try it online!
Input target value and the array of nums, output a set of tuples.

Charcoal, 57 bytes
Ｗ⁻θυＦ№θ⌊ι⊞υ⌊ι≔⟦⟧θＦＥＸ²ＬυＥ⌕Ａ⮌⍘ι²1§υλＦ⁼⁵ＬιＦ⁼ηΣιＦ¬№θι⊞θιＥθ⭆¹ι

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:
Ｗ⁻θυＦ№θ⌊ι⊞υ⌊ι

Sort the input list.
≔⟦⟧θ

Start with no results.
ＦＥＸ²ＬυＥ⌕Ａ⮌⍘ι²1§υλ

Get all subsets of the sorted list.
Ｆ⁼⁵Ｌι

Filter on those that have length 5.
Ｆ⁼ηΣι

Filter on those with the desired total.
Ｆ¬№θι

Filter on those that are distinct.
⊞θι

Keep only the distinct subsets of 5 with the correct total.
Ｅθ⭆¹ι

Pretty-print the found subsets.

Vyxal, 20 bytes
→tṖƛ5Þİ_;'∑←t=;λsS;ε

First Vyxal submission 
Almost certainly golf-able.
Explained
→t                      # Assign the target to t
  Ṗ                     # Get all permutations of the input list
   ƛ5Þİ_;               # Taking the first 5 elements of each permutation
         '∑←t=;         # Where the sum is equal to t
               λsS;ε    # Uniqueify by the sorted string

Try it Online!

Uiua, 11 bytes
◴▽=⤚≡/+⧅<5⍆

Try it!
◴▽=⤚≡/+⧅<5⍆
           ⍆ # sort
        ⧅<5   # get quintuples
 ▽=⤚≡/+       # keep those for which the sum equals the target
◴             # and deduplicate


Japt, 12 bytes
Outputs an empty array if no solution is possible.
Íà5 â fÈx ¶V

Try it
Íà5 â fÈx ¶V     :Implicit input of array U & target integer V
Í                :Sort U
 à5              :Combinations of length 5
    â            :Deduplicate
      f          :Filter by
       È         :Passing through the following function
        x        :  Reduce by addition
          ¶V     :  Equal to V?


Why doesn't Í pop up in the 'Search method' in the online compiler? I searched for sort and it didn't pop up, and even if I search directly for Í, only the lowercase versions pop up.  (Hence why I mentioned ñ as sort instead.)

@KevinCruijssen, Í is a (shortcut)[https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=zeA1IOIgZsh4ILZW&input=WzEsMCw5LDYsNSwwXQoyMQotUg#docs-shortcuts] for n2<space>. It's primary intent is for use on strings, where the n method converts to an integer and the 2 argument specifies from binary. The n method when used on an array, though, sorts the array and the 2 is ignored as the method doesn't expect an integer as an argument.

JavaScript (V8), 91 bytes
f=([c,...x],s,n=R=[])=>1/n[4]?s||R[n.sort()]||print(R[n]=n):1/c&&f(x,s,n)^f(x,s-c,[...n,c])

Try it online!
JavaScript (Node.js), 97 bytes
f=([c,...x],s,n=R=[])=>1/n[4]?s||R[n.sort()]?[]:[R[n]=n]:1/c?[...f(x,s,n),...f(x,s-c,[...n,c])]:x

Try it online!
JavaScript (Node.js), 98 bytes
f=(x,s,i=R={},...n)=>1/n[4]?s||R[n.sort()]?[]:[R[n]=n]:x.flatMap((e,j)=>i<=j?[]:f(x,s-e,j,...n,e))

Try it online!
Dedup

f=([c,...x],s,n=R=[])=>1/n[4]?R[n.sort()]??=s||+print(n):1/c?f(x,s,n)^f(x,s-c,[...n,c]):x

Vyxal, 8 bytes
s5ḋU'∑⁰=

Try it Online!
-2 from emanresu
Takes list then target.
Explained
s5ḋU'∑⁰=­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
s         # ‎⁡Sort the input. This helps with uniquification later
 5ḋ       # ‎⁢Get all combinations without replacement of length 5
   U      # ‎⁣Filter out duplicate instances of combinations
    '     # ‎⁤Keep combinations where:
     ∑ =  # ‎⁢⁡  The sum equals
      ⁰   # ‎⁢⁢  The target


Created with the help of Luminespire.

@Arnauld I allow it to be 0-indexed or 1-indexed.

@Arnauld I don't see why it wouldn't, regardless of 0 or 1 indexing.

@Arnauld "You may return the answer in any order. For example, given the array [-5,-2,-2,1,3,4,6] and target 0, you could return any permutation of [[-5,-2,-2,3,6]]."

My bad. I was reading the 1st condition as 0 <= a<b<c<d<e < n from the beginning.

05AB1E, 8 bytes
{5.ÆÙʒOQ

Inputs in the order \$array,target\$. Outputs [] if there is no valid result.
Try it online or verify all test cases.
Explanation:
{         # Sort the first (implicit) input-list
 5.Æ      # Get all 5-element combinations of this list
    Ù     # Uniquify this list of quintuplets
     ʒ    # Filter it by:
      O   #  Where the sum of the quintuplet
       Q  #  Equals the second (implicit) input-integer
          # (after which the result is output implicitly)


JavaScript (V8), 91 bytes
f=([v,...a],n,o=q=[])=>o[4]?n||q[o.sort()]||print(q[o]=o):v+1&&f(a,n-v,[...o,[v]])|f(a,n,o)

Try it online!
Commented
f = (             // f is a recursive function taking:
  [v,             //   v = next value from the input array
      ...a],      //   a[] = remaining values
  n,              //   n = target sum
  o =             //   o[] = current output array
  q = []          //   q = object to keep track of output arrays
) =>              //
o[4] ?            // if o[4] is defined:
  n ||            //   unless n is not 0
  q[o.sort()] ||  //   or q[o] is defined (with o[] sorted),
  print(q[o] = o) //   print o[] and set q[o]
:                 // else:
  v + 1 &&        //   unless v is undefined,
  f(              //   do a 1st recursive call:
    a,            //     pass a[]
    n - v,        //     subtract v from n
    [...o, [v]]   //     append [v] to o[]
  ) |             //   end of recursive call
  f(a, n, o)      //   do a 2nd recursive call with everything unchanged


Python 3, 755 674 bytes
-81 bytes thanks to @corvus_192
def f (n,t):
    n.sort()
    s=[]
    for i in range(len(n)-4):
        if i>0 and n[i]==n[i-1]:
            continue
        for j in range(i+1,len(n)-3):
            for k in range(j+1,len(n)-2):
                l,m=k+1,len(n)-1
                while l<m:
                    a=n[i]+n[j]+n[k]+n[l]+n[m]
                    if a<t:
                        l+=1
                    elif a>t:
                        m-=1
                    else:
                        s.append((n[i],n[j],n[k],n[l],n[m]))
                        l+=1
                        while n[l]==n[l-1] and l<m:
                            l+=1
    k=[]
    for b in list(set(s)):
        k.append(list(b))
    return k

(returns a list of sorted lists.)
Old 755:
def fiveSum (nums,target):
    nums.sort()
    s=[]
    for i in range(len(nums)-4):
        if i>0 and nums[i]==nums[i-1]:
            continue
        for j in range(i+1,len(nums)-3):
            for k in range(j+1,len(nums)-2):
                l,m=k+1,len(nums)-1
                while l<m:
                    a=nums[i]+nums[j]+nums[k]+nums[l]+nums[m]
                    if a<target:
                        l+=1
                    elif a>target:
                        m-=1
                    else:
                        s.append((nums[i],nums[j],nums[k],nums[l],nums[m]))
                        l+=1
                        while nums[l]==nums[l-1] and l<m:
                            l+=1
    k=[]
    for b in list(set(s)):
        k.append(list(b))
    return k

Explanation:
def fiveSum (nums,target):
    nums.sort()                                                             # does NOT return all 4 solutions for the last case if removed, unsure why
    s=[]                                                                    # ^ (only returns two/four arrays)
    for i in range(len(nums)-4):                                            # i < j < k < l < m
        if i>0 and nums[i]==nums[i-1]:                                      # later loops will cover all of the
            continue                                                        # other cases, so no need to recurse through them again
        for j in range(i+1,len(nums)-3):                                    # for j in range
            for k in range(j+1,len(nums)-2):                                # for k in range
                l,m=k+1,len(nums)-1                                         # No more "_ in range" needed anymore
                while l<m:                                                  # i < j < k < l < m
                    a=nums[i]+nums[j]+nums[k]+nums[l]+nums[m]               # The sum
                    if a<target:                                            # check if nums[0]+nums[1]+...+nums[4] == target
                        l+=1                                                # it probably doesn't, so increment l by 1
                    elif a>target:                                          # if overshoot
                        m-=1                                                # if it does, decrement m by 1
                    else:
                        s.append((nums[i],nums[j],nums[k],nums[l],nums[m])) # append to list
                        l+=1
                        while nums[l]==nums[l-1] and l<m:                   # More incrementation! (Yay?)
                            l+=1
    k=[]                                                                    # The final list
    for b in list(set(s)):
        k.append(list(b))
    return k                                                                # return List[List[str]]


Try to use one-letter variable names to save even more bytes

Scala 3, 36 bytes
t=>_ combinations 5 filter(_.sum==t)

Attempt This Online!
A function of type Int => Seq[Int] => Iterator[Seq[Int]].

R, 52 bytes
\(x,n)unique(t(combn(x,5,sort)[,combn(x,5,sum)==n]))

Attempt This Online!
Returns quintuplets as rows of a matrix.

Haskell + hgl, 21 bytes
nB sr<<ss5><fl<eq^.sm

Attempt This Online!
Explanation
The order of operations is a bit strange here.

ss5 get all quintuples
fl filter those that ...
sm their sum ...
eq is equal to the input
nB sr remove duplicates after sorting.

Reflection
We have some pretty good builtins here. The only 3-byte builtin is ss5 which definitely should not be a 2-byte function. It seems like we use a lot of glue, but it's not an area I can see much improvement. I really have all the glue I want. There's no parens and we don't even use any 3-byte composes.
It seems long but I don't really know how it could be shorter.
The only possible improvement is to make nB sr a builtin. I don't really know if this would be useful in the long term.

Arturo, 51 bytes
$[a,t][a|sort|combine.by:5|select=>[t=∑&]|unique]



APL, 63 chars
{⍺{⍵/⍨(⍺∘=+/∧5∘=∘≢)¨⍵}{0=≢⍵:1⍴⊂⍬⋄⊃,/(⊃⍵){(⊂⍵),⊂⍵,1⍴⍺}¨(∇1↓⍵)}⍵}

Takes the target on the left and the list of numbers on the right.
Explanation, broken out slightly into a helper function:
combos←{0=≢⍵:1⍴⊂⍬⋄⊃,/(⊃⍵){(⊂⍵),⊂⍵,1⍴⍺}¨(∇1↓⍵)}    ⍝ Recursively generate all combinations of the input array
        0=≢⍵:                                    ⍝ If the input is empty
             1⍴⊂⍬                                ⍝    return a one-element array containing an empty array
                                      (∇1↓⍵)     ⍝ Otherwise recursively call with the tail of the list
                     (⊃⍵){           }¨          ⍝ And apply to each result with the head of the list as the left input
                               ⊂⍵,1⍴⍺            ⍝ Concat the right input with an array made from the left input
                          (⊂⍵),                  ⍝ And concat with the input itself
                ⊃,/                              ⍝ Join and disclose to not further nest the result

{⍺{⍵/⍨(⍺∘=+/∧5∘=∘≢)¨⍵} combos ⍵}
{                  ¨⍵}                           ⍝ Take all the possible combinations
   ⍵/⍨                                           ⍝ And replicate those that pass:
      (     ∧     )                              ⍝     the AND of
       ⍺∘=+/                                     ⍝         the left input matches their sum
             5∘=∘≢                               ⍝         the right input has 5 elements


Maple, 57 bytes
(n,t)->[{select(x->add(x)=t,combinat:-choose(n,5))[]}[]];

Explanation:
Input: n = nums (list), t = target.
combinat:-choose outputs combinations in lex order.
select filters for those that add to the target.
conversion from list to set {...[]} makes unique, then [...[]] converts back to a list.
